# Starting with E-Commerce and Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, e-commerce

I have a website and I will have to implement e payments. The problem is that I have 0 knowledge for these kind of things, my website even runs on http not https..

I know that I can use active_merchant to process payments, but how do I get started?

Any resources please for beginners?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been thinking about doing a tutorial on this - we've made a basic Rails e-commerce app you can view at http://firststopcosmeticshop.co.uk

It's not completely finished, but should give you an ideas as to how you could create an e-commerce application for people. I'll detail some things about the structure here for you:

--

**E-Commerce**

There are several features to consider with e-commerce applications:

> 1. How the "cart" will persist
> 2. How to show the products on screen
> 3. How to manage the options for the products
> 4. How to manage the "backend" of the store

I'll describe some of the functionality for these on here. I can't write too much because it will end up confusing you...

---

**1. Cart**

If you're going to make an e-commerce app, you need to make a cart. We used a [session-based model](http://railscasts.com/episodes/119-session-based-model); however another way is to create a `Cart` model itself, which relies on the database

The bottom line with the cart is you need a way to persist the data. Data persistence is simply the way in which you're able to make data "stay" in the browser even between requests to your Rails server. As Rails is a [stateless](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol) framework, it treats every request as "naked" - meaning if you want to keep your data, you have to use some way of identifying it.

For our cart, we used a very simple system of `sessions` - whereby if you add a new product to the cart, it will add that product ID to your session, thus giving you a persistent cart store:

[[I can include code if you want it]]

--

**2. Products**

You'll be able to create a `Product` model:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :products, only: [:index, :show] 

#app/models/product.rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :category
end

#app/controllers/products_controller.rb
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
   def index
       @products = Product.all
   end

   def show
       @product = Product.find params[:id]
   end
end

#app/views/products/index.html.erb
<% @products.each do |product| %>
   <%= product.name %>
<% end %>
```

--

**3. Product Options**

You'll also need a way to manage product options. If you buy a t-shirt, you'll want to make sure you have different `sizes` etc. This is tricky (especially for cosmetics where you have to accommodate so many different options), but we found a way:

```
#app/models/option.rb
class Option < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :product_options
   has_many :products, through: :product_options
end

#app/models/product_option.rb
class ProductOption < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :product
   belongs_to :option
end

#app/models/product.rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :product_options
   has_many :options, through: :product_options
end
```

This will give you the ability to call `@product.options` etc.

The trick here is to populate the `ProductOption` model with a series of different attributes pertaining to the option itself. For example:

```
#products
id | title |  price  | created_at | updated_at
x  | xbox  |  399.99 |      x     |     x

#product_options
id | product_id | option_id | name | created_at | updated_at
x  |     1      |     2     | blue |     x      |     x
x  |     1      |     1     | wifi |     x      |     x
x  |     1      |     3     | chip |     x      |     x
x  |     1      |     2     | pink |     x      |     x

#options
id | name       | created_at | updated_at 
x  | accessory  |     x      |     x
y  | colour     |     x      |     x 
z  | upgrades   |     x      |     x
```

This will give you massive extensibility - providing you with the ability to create a truly compelling structure for the store & your products

--

**4. Backend**

You can do this by using a [namespace](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing):

```
#config/routes.rb
namespace :admin do
   root "products#index"
   resources :products, only: [:index, :new, :create] #-> domain.com/admin/products/new
end
```

This allows you to create a "mini app" inside the `/admin` folder:

```
#app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb
class Admin::ProductsController < ApplicationController
   before_action :authenticate_user!

   def index
      @products = Product.all
   end

   def new 
      @product = Product.new
   end

   def create
      @product = Product.new product_params
      @product.save
   end

   private

   def product_params
       params.require(:product).permit(:title, :price)
   end
end
```

You'll want to authenticate the admin area using [`Devise`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise), allowing you to create a private area for users / admins only.

---

**Update**

To handle payments, you'll be best using [ActiveMerchant](https://github.com/Shopify/active_merchant)

This has been extracted from some of the Shopify source - is the most comprehensive payment gateway manager for Rails. I would *highly* recommend using it, especially if you're new.

I won't go into details (you can see how to set it up with [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/145-integrating-active-merchant)) - to get it to work, I'd create an "orders" controller & model:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :orders, only: [:new, :create], path_names: { new: "" }, path: :order

#app/models/order.rb
Class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
end

#app/controllers/orders_controller.rb
class OrdersController < ApplicationController

   def new
       #start payment here
   end

   def create
      #if payment successful, continue
      @order = Order.new order_params
      @order.save
   end

   private

   def order_params
       params.require(:order).permit(:x, :y, :z)
   end
end
```

This allows you to then call the following URL: `domain.com/order`, from which you'll be able to input your payment details, send the payment to PayPal or similar, and then return the buyer to a "Thank You" page of sorts

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer! But I was wondering how you deal with the banks/gateways and stuff? My website will just take one payment, it is not product related

Comment: Hey bud! You should have been a little more specific in your question!! I'll write an update for you!

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely look into the Stripe API

https://stripe.com/docs/api

Answer (score 0):

I would say if you don't understand this to start with a project that can get you started.  Check out https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/e_commerce

spree & ror_ecommerce are the top 2 choices.  Disclaimer I wrote ror_ecommerce so I am biased.  The simple fact is these projects have a good start handling the data model & security.  Feel free to ping me via https://github.com/drhenner